# Error: Failed to lookup view in express + jade

Tags: javascript, express, pug

this is the code I have

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

exports.makeObservable = function(state, path, cb) {
    app.get(path, function(req, res){
        res.render('observable.jade', state);
        //call callback with new user
        cb(req);
    });

    app.listen('9999'); 
}
```

Whenever I try to reach the `path` I receive the following error:
 `Error: Failed to lookup view "observable.jade"`. I also tried to pass `observable` without the `.jade` but it gives the same error. I have both observable.jade and layout.jade in my `/views` folder.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Can't reproduce the error. If you want a quick guess, maybe express is doing the lookup in the directory `__dirname + 'views'` which is wherever the script is running, for example, if the script lives in `/herman/code/myapp/scripts`, it will look in `/herman/code/myapp/scripts/views`, instead of `/herman/code/myapp/views`... Send more data, please.

Comment: To debug this go to line 493 of express/lib/application.js and add console.log(view.path); This will log what path your app is trying to hit.

Comment: Thanks to both. It's true that I had my `/view` folder outside the running directory of the script, but also putting it in the right directory didn't solve the problem. I tried with the `console.log()` but it printed out `undefined`. What can I do?

Comment: By printing `view` instead that `view.path` I could notice that the script was indeed run from a totally different folder. I managed to solve the problem in the end. Thanks. :)

Comment: Somebody should take my answer + herman's and make it into a real answer cause this could be helpful for others.

Comment: Yes definitely. I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem thanks to the suggestions in the comments. First of all I checked if the directory from which the script was executing contained the directory `/views` where I put the `.jade` files. I couldn't solve the problem at first since I couldn't figure from which this script was executed, so I put a `console.log(view)` at line 493 in `/express/lib/application.js`. It printed out the `view` object that contained the root from which the script was executed, thus I moved the `/views` folder there and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: I have my views in an adjacent directory (ie root/server, root/client), and was having the same issues described here. The one thing I did differently than the OP, was to prepend a '/' in my app.set when climbing out of the server directory; ie:

this: app.set('views', __dirname + '**/**../client/');

instead of: app.set('views', __dirname + '../client/');

HTH

(Thanks a TON to the OP and Pickels!)